# Does the Jinja2 templating language have the concept of 'here' (current directory)?

Tags: python, jinja2

Does Jinja2 support template-relative paths e.g. `%(here)s/other/template.html`, to include other templates relative to the current template's place in the filesystem?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I do not believe so.  Typically you include or extend other templates by specifying their paths relative to the root of whatever template loader and environment you're using.

So let's say your templates are all in `/path/to/templates` and you've set up Jinja like so:

```
import jinja2
template_dir = '/path/to/templates'
loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir)
environment = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
```

Now, if you'd like to include `/path/to/templates/includes/sidebar.html` in the `/path/to/templates/index.html` template, you'd write the following in your `index.html`:

```
{% include 'includes/sidebar.html' %}
```

and Jinja would figure out how to find it.

Answer (score 22):

Just to add to Will McCutchen's answer,

You can have multiple directories in your loader. It then searches in each of the directories (in order) until it finds the template.

for example, if you wanted to have "sidebar.html" instead of "/includes/sidebar.html" then have:

```
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(
        [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"templates/includes"),
         os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"templates")])
```

instead of

```
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"templates"))
```

Answer (score 10):

According to the documentation for [jinja2.Environment.join_path()](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/#jinja2.Environment.join_path), support for relative template paths is possible by overriding join_path() to implement "template path joining".

```
class RelEnvironment(jinja2.Environment):
    """Override join_path() to enable relative template paths."""
    def join_path(self, template, parent):
        return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(parent), template)
```

Comment: This worked for me after I wrapped the `join` with `os.path.normpath` otherwise it complains trying to resolve paths like 'parent/../child/template.html'

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to overcome this limitation, would be with a jinja2 extension that will allow to [import relative template names](https://gist.github.com/wooyek/8d4c37d684a5ba38b8c1)

Something in the likes of:

```
from jinja2.ext import Extension
import re


class RelativeInclude(Extension):
    """Allows to import relative template names"""
    tags = set(['include2'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(RelativeInclude, self).__init__(environment)
        self.matcher = re.compile("\.*")

    def parse(self, parser):
        node = parser.parse_include()
        template = node.template.as_const()
        if template.startswith("."):
            # determine the number of go ups
            up = len(self.matcher.match(template).group())
            # split the current template name into path elements
            # take elements minus the number of go ups
            seq = parser.name.split("/")[:-up]
            # extend elements with the relative path elements
            seq.extend(template.split("/")[1:])
            template = "/".join(seq)
            node.template.value = template
        return node
```