# Pyinstaller Jinja2 TemplateNotFound

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2, pyinstaller

I am using `pyinstaller` to build my flask application,
everything is working fine except I get problems with Jinja2 templates.

It gave me `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound`,

I tried to put `from app import template` which is the templates folder, but it didn't work (I guess since they don't contain any `py` file).

I also tried changing the `.spec` file to include the `templates` folder

```
added_files = [
         ( '..\\CommerceApp\\app\\templates', 'templates' ),
         ( '..\\CommerceApp\\app\\static', 'static' )
        ]

a = Analysis(['..\\CommerceApp\\run.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\PythonProjects\\CommerceAppExe'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
```

But it didn't work either, same result as if I copy the folder manually by myself.

Is there any way to include Template bundled together with the .exe?

---

**Edit**

This is my `spec` file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['..\\CommerceApp_withPyInstaller\\run.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\PythonProjects\\CommerceAppExe'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='SupplyTracker',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='SupplyTracker')
```

---

**Edit 2**

Accepted Answer changed to [`gmas80`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36160856/4162778) because it fixes the problem.

**Edit 3**

Also I just realize, I can just make a new folder with my package name and fill in the static templates `css`, `html`, etc, and it is gonna work (similar result from what gmas80 script does)

Comment: Create a 1-folder frozen application and check if all the template files have been collected!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask application built using pyinstaller not rendering index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149892/flask-application-built-using-pyinstaller-not-rendering-index-html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe that the issue is what is described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35816876/2741329. I have just been able to freeze an application with `Jinja2`.

In my spec file I use this approach to collect all the templates:

```
from PyInstaller.building.build_main import Analysis, PYZ, EXE, COLLECT, BUNDLE, TOC


def collect_pkg_data(package, include_py_files=False, subdir=None):
    import os
    from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import get_package_paths, remove_prefix, PY_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS

    # Accept only strings as packages.
    if type(package) is not str:
        raise ValueError

    pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths(package)
    if subdir:
        pkg_dir = os.path.join(pkg_dir, subdir)
    # Walk through all file in the given package, looking for data files.
    data_toc = TOC()
    for dir_path, dir_names, files in os.walk(pkg_dir):
        for f in files:
            extension = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
            if include_py_files or (extension not in PY_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS):
                source_file = os.path.join(dir_path, f)
                dest_folder = remove_prefix(dir_path, os.path.dirname(pkg_base) + os.sep)
                dest_file = os.path.join(dest_folder, f)
                data_toc.append((dest_file, source_file, 'DATA'))

    return data_toc

pkg_data = collect_pkg_data('<YOUR LIB HERE>')
```

Then add `pkg_data` to the `COLLECT` (1-folder) or to the `EXE` (1-file) .spec.

In the 1-folder solution, you should be able to find all your templates in the created sub-folder.

---

**Edit**

This might work (assuming that you have a package (i.e., you have an `__init__.py`) following these suggestions: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/):

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

# <<< START ADDED PART    
from PyInstaller.building.build_main import Analysis, PYZ, EXE, COLLECT, BUNDLE, TOC


def collect_pkg_data(package, include_py_files=False, subdir=None):
    import os
    from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import get_package_paths, remove_prefix, PY_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS

    # Accept only strings as packages.
    if type(package) is not str:
        raise ValueError

    pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths(package)
    if subdir:
        pkg_dir = os.path.join(pkg_dir, subdir)
    # Walk through all file in the given package, looking for data files.
    data_toc = TOC()
    for dir_path, dir_names, files in os.walk(pkg_dir):
        for f in files:
            extension = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
            if include_py_files or (extension not in PY_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS):
                source_file = os.path.join(dir_path, f)
                dest_folder = remove_prefix(dir_path, os.path.dirname(pkg_base) + os.sep)
                dest_file = os.path.join(dest_folder, f)
                data_toc.append((dest_file, source_file, 'DATA'))

    return data_toc

pkg_data = collect_pkg_data('<yourapplication>')  # <<< Put the name of your package here
# <<< END ADDED PART    

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['..\\CommerceApp_withPyInstaller\\run.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\PythonProjects\\CommerceAppExe'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='SupplyTracker',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               pkg_data,  # <<< Add here the collected files
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='SupplyTracker')
```

Comment: Hey sorry if I don't know, how do you put the `pkg_data` attribute into `COLLECT` in `spec` file? I tried putting the `pathname` of the script (../path/to/pkg_data.py) but it didn't work. Should I `import` the script in my  main script? or put it somewhere in `Analysis` attributes? Thanks

Comment: @kingathur61 : Why don't you put your whole spec file in the question body? So that I can edit it as I believe that may work.

Comment: @kingathur61: added a new part to my answer

Comment: Wow, thanks! `collect_pkg_data('flask_appbuilder')` did lots of magic collecting for me.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) package uses the [`pkg_resources`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html) API which is not supported by `PyInstaller`. The `pkg_resources` module is provided via the [`setuptools`](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/) package.

From the [`FAQ`](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ) page of [`pyinstaller`](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/):

> pkg_resources is currently not supported by PyInstaller. This means
>   that an application using a library which uses the the pkg_resources
>   API will probably not work out of the box. The only situation in which
>   it works is when it's being used on .egg files (see above). For
>   details follow issue #183.

Comment: Ah, I see, so until pyinstaller is updated, there is nothing I can do right?

Comment: @Forge and @kingathur61: ``jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound`` is not related to ``pkg_resources``. Otherwise, it would have been something different: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1898

Answer (score 0):

You can embed jinja2 templates by tweaking generated .spec file.

1. 1st run in automatic mode: pyinstaller yourscript.py --name yourapp --onefile
2. edit yourscript.spec to add templates directory in Analysis

   datas=[('yourscript/templates/*.html', 'yourscript/templates/')],
3. Generate one file installer from spec file: pyinstaller yourscript.spec