# Pyinstaller - Flask template not found "bootstrap/base.html"

Tags: pyinstaller, flask-bootstrap

I am trying to make a distributable of a flask application. Everything works fine when running locally. When an executable is generated with pyinstaller it gives me the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app

  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
  File "site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
  File "app.py", line 39, in index
  File "site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 140, in render_template
  File "site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 120, in _render
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: bootstrap/base.html
```

I am using the flask bootstrap as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318142/jinja2-exceptions-templatenotfound-bootstrap-base-html).

Comment: please refer this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811448/pyinstaller-jinja2-templatenotfound/36160856#36160856

Answer (score 2):

create a new python file named 'hook-flask_bootstrap.py', inside of this paste the following:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('flask_bootstrap')
```

Now when you run pyinstaller provide the path to this 'hook-flask_bootstrap.py' file:

```
--additional-hooks-dir=PATH (If relative path, just use .)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I later decided not to use the flask bootstrap and designed the webpage using bootstrap in HTML. Although I did not test this, I hope this works for someone who comes here.

Comment: I tried this, and it worked for me. Thanks Tristin.