# pyinstaller Template not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller to create an executable, but I am getting these errors when I run the executable:

> ```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
> >       File "flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
> >       File "flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
> >       File "flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
> >       File "flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
> >       File "testforms.py", line 13, in my_form
> >       File "flask/templating.py", line 133, in render_template
> >       File "jinja2/environment.py", line 851, in get_or_select_template
> >       File "jinja2/environment.py", line 812, in get_template
> >       File "jinja2/environment.py", line 774, in _load_template
> >       File "flask/templating.py", line 57, in get_source
> >       File "flask/templating.py", line 85, in _get_source_fast
> >       TemplateNotFound: template.html
> ```

When I run this script locallly, it all works fine.

Here is the script:

```
from flask import Flask                               
from flask import request                             
from flask import render_template                     
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')    

@app.route('/')                                       
def my_form():                                        
    return render_template('/template.html' )         

    @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])                     
 def my_form_post():                                   

    text = request.form['text']                       
    processed_text = text.upper()                     
    print processed_text                              
    return processed_text                             

if __name__ == '__main__':                            
    app.run()
```

To build the executable I used:

```
pyinstaller --onefile testforms.py
```

I also tried:

```
return render_template('template.html' )
```

Comment: I also tried:   return render_template('template.html' )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask application built using pyinstaller not rendering index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149892/flask-application-built-using-pyinstaller-not-rendering-index-html)

Answer (score 0):

i encountered the same issue. But i didn't make one file. I just copy static and template folder and paste in "dist/main"  folder. Its works for me

Comment: Doesn't it defeat the purpose of bundling the app into a package (using PyInstaller) and distributing it as an executable?