# Python Flask Divisional Accessing Base Templates

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html#divisional

Divisional Structure Is like Django Structure. I want to make Reusable Modular component in Flask and just call blueprint for that feature.
yourapp/

```
__init__.py
admin/
    __init__.py
    views.py
    static/
    templates/
home/
    __init__.py
    views.py
    static/
    templates/
control_panel/
    __init__.py
    views.py
    static/
    templates/
models.py
```

Problem is that i don't know how to access the base temple form jinja

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

from a different templates folder

because in the blueprints i Specified a the template location.

```
contact = Blueprint('contact', __name__, url_prefix='/contact',template_folder='./templates')
```

Any thoughts on the file structure on flask or how to get the same base template to all the blueprints?

Comment: It looks possible with this [custom jinja2 extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24600205/6085135).