# Display combined but unrendered Jinja templates

Tags: python, jinja2

I would like to compile (not sure if that's the right term) all of the templates as "raw" or unparsed/rendered templates for display.

I've tried using changing `variable_start_string` and `variable_end_string` which does partially work but, other types of blocks are rendered (such as `{% for %}`)

For example, given two templates:

template `parent.j2`:

```py
some text
{% for x in y %}
 {{ x }}
{% endfor %}
{% include 'child.j2' %}
```

template `child.j2`

```
{% set things to [0,1,2] %}
{% for thing in things %}
 {{ thing }}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to output them as:

```
some text
{% for x in y %}
 {{ x }}
{% endfor %}
{% set things to [0,1,2] %}
{% for thing in things %}
 {{ thing }}
{% endfor %}
```

At best, I can use something like:

```py
def combine_without_render(self, template):
        env = Environment(
            loader=FileSystemLoader(self.template_dir),
            variable_start_string='{[(*&',
            variable_end_string='&*)]}'
        )
        template = env.get_template(template)
            return template.render()
```

to get something like:

```
 {{ x }}
 {{ thing }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can use {% raw %}..

```
{% raw %}

some text 
{% for x in y %} 
{{ x }} 
{% endfor %} 
{% endraw %}
{% include 'child.j2' %}
```

**EDIT**:
as i can see, it works:

parent.j2:

```
{% raw -%}
some text
{% for x in y %}
 {{ x }}
{% endfor %}
{% endraw -%}
{% include 'child.j2' %}
```

child.j2:

```
{% raw -%}
{% set things to [0,1,2] %}
{% for thing in things %}
 {{ thing }}
{% endfor %}
{% endraw -%}
```

Python:

```
import jinja2

templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./")
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
TEMPLATE_FILE = "parent.j2"
template = templateEnv.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILE)
print(template.render())
```

OUTPUT:

```
some text
{% for x in y %}
 {{ x }}
{% endfor %}
{% set things to [0,1,2] %}
{% for thing in things %}
 {{ thing }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that escapes the control blocks and include/import as well. I'm beginning to think there's no way to do this outside of some custom code to assemble the templates outside of jinja.

Comment: Really interesting. So in practice, I'd need to load the template as a string and wrap any non-indent/include lines in `{% raw -%}{% endraw -%}. This seems to answer the question for sure since any way it's done will be hacky. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with another method. This seems to work well but similar to a previous answer, is limited to includes. This does require [relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655911/7696385) for the environment and to preface any includes with their path relative to the base environment:

`parent.j2`:

```
some text
{% include "/sub_dir/child.j2" %}
```

It's called recursively on each file until it reaches the end and then outputs a string:

```py
def _build_stream(self, base_template):
        """
        Recursive method to build an unrendered single template from all
        sub templates included.
        """

        parent = False

        if self._stream_out is None:
            self._stream_out = [] # The final output stream
            parent = True  #When recursion is finished, we can post-process the output


        # This match would need to be changed if you want to include something other
        # than {% include "x" %}
        include_re = re.compile('^.*\{\%\s+include\s+\"/(.*)\".*$', re.IGNORECASE)


        # Open the base template and then recurse through any includes
        # If one is found, call the same method
        # If a line doesnt' match the regex, put it in the stream output

        with open(os.path.join(self.template_dir,base_template), 
                                'r') as base_fh:
            base_template = base_fh.readlines()

        for b_line in base_template:
            b_line.rstrip()
            matches = include_re.match(b_line)
            if matches is not None:
                self._build_stream(os.path.join(
                    self.template_dir, matches.group(1)
                ))
            else:
                self._stream_out.append(b_line)

        if parent is True:
            # If this is the top-level, join the lines for printing

            output =  '\n'.join(self._stream_out)
            self._stream_out = None
            return output
```

Super hacky but, it works.